# connect a headless raspberry pi zero to a WPA2 Mixed WiFi network

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w, wpa

I'm trying to connect my rpi zero in a headless mode into a WIFI network configured in a WPA mixed mode.

More specifically I can get the following info from the router.

```
Security-Mode: WPA2-Mixed
Encryption: TKIP + AES
Wireless network mode: Mixed
SSID: HANET
Passphrase: @123ABCwe@
```

So according with  the different articles that I've found online, inside the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file I'm having the following:

```
zcountry=GR
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="HANET"
    #ssid="ComputerCenter"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="@123ABCwe@"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=TKIP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    #key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

But it seems that RPI never get connected to the wifi because it's not listed inside the router nor found with a simple subnet scan.

Any ideas?

Comment: `zcountry`? should that just be `country` ... anyway, all I have in my supplicant file after `country` `ctrl_interface` and `update_config`  in the `network` setting `ssid`, `psk` and `key_mgmt` entries - perhaps try with just those and see if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was with the typo in `zcountry` parameter that Jaromanda X noticed. I turned the `zcountry` into `country` and now it's working.